# Router path for page navigation

Tags: meteor, iron-router

we have the problem with the router when we navigate from one to another page.

Suppose when we are in template1 and we need to go to templete2.Then we do Router.go(/templete2) right.I need in the URl templete1/templete2.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following in your router.js file

```
Router.route('template1/template2',function() {  
    this.render('template2');
 });
```

Comment: There is another problem images not loading in template2.images are there in public folder. @syed zoheb

Comment: if your image is in public folder. use the url as `background: url(/images/bg.png)` instead of `background:url(public/images/bg.png)`. you don't need to specify the `public folder` in the url when you are accessing a static file.